# mount cifs too long due to chown for each file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, mount, cifs

I need to run an application on a VM , where I can do my set up in a script that will be run as root when the machine is built.

In this script I would like to mount a windows FS, so using CIFS.
So I am writing the following in the fstab:

```
//win/dir /my/dir cifs noserverino,ro,uid=1002,gid=1002,credentials=/root/.secret 0 0
```

After this, still in the same script, I try to mount it:

```
mount /my/dir
```

THat results in output of 2 lines for each file:

```
chown: changing ownership of `/my/dir/afile' Read-only file system
```

Because I have a lot of files, this takes forever...

With the same fstab I have asked an admin to manually mount the same directory : 
   `sudo mount /my/dir`

-> this is very quick with NO extra output.

I assume the difference of behavior is due to the fact that the script is run as root.
Any idea how to avoid the issue while keeping the idea of the script run as root  ( this is not under my control )

Cheers.
Renaud

Comment: I've never seen the mount command try to run chown. Is your script running chown?

Comment: Script is not running chown. Mount command does.